# How to see the current routed connections?

Tags: linux, networking, router, statistics

I'm running a router that is using linux; I want to see connection statistics from internal network to external network(s) (NAT router); how do I do this? I've tried using `netstat` but of course its only the local router connections.

I can see the connection information if I setup something like an IDS and mirror; but I do not want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool known as `netstat-nat`; that seems to work. However, I could not get it to compile for ARM.

So, I wrote my own tool that does what `netstat-nat` does; although easier to port to other architectures: `nat-stat` that is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/bbb31/nat-stat).

To manually see the connections take a look at `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` or `/proc/net/ip_conntrack`.